# java.lang.ClassCastException: Activity cannot be cast to Adapter while trying to convert Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, casting, android-adapter

I'm trying to convert `Activity` to `Fragment` and I'm sruggling to understand how to do it properly with this one.

Basically, I'm trying to adapt [this MainActivity](https://github.com/JorgeAmVF/android-room-markdown-notepad/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jorgeamvf/roommarkdownnotepad/MainActivity.java) so as it fits a bottom navigation bar and besides getting lost in contexts, I'm dealing with this specific issue:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.com, PID: 5213
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.com.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.com.adapter.NotesAdapter$OnNoteItemClick
>           at com.example.com.adapter.NotesAdapter.(NotesAdapter.java:27)
>           at com.example.com.RoomMarkdownActivity.onCreateView(RoomMarkdownActivity.java:54)
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5213 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Here is a copy of the piece of code I'm working on:

```
public class RoomMarkdownActivity extends Fragment implements NotesAdapter.OnNoteItemClick {

    public static RoomMarkdownActivity newInstance() { return new RoomMarkdownActivity(); }

    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public TextView textViewMsg;
    public NoteDatabase noteDatabase;
    public List<Note> notes;
    public NotesAdapter notesAdapter;
    public int pos;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.room_markdown_activity, container, false);

        textViewMsg = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_empty);
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(listener);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        notes = new ArrayList<>();
        notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
        noteDatabase = NoteDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
        new RetrieveTask(this).execute();

        return view;
    }

    private static class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Note>> {

        private WeakReference<RoomMarkdownActivity> activityReference;

        RetrieveTask(RoomMarkdownActivity context) {
            activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Note> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            if (activityReference.get() != null)
                return activityReference.get().noteDatabase.getNoteDao().getNotes();
            else
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Note> notes) {
            if (notes != null && notes.size() > 0) {
                activityReference.get().notes.clear();
                activityReference.get().notes.addAll(notes);
                activityReference.get().textViewMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                activityReference.get().notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), RoomMarkdownAddNoteActivity.class), 100);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode > 0) {
            if (resultCode == 1) {
                notes.add((Note) data.getSerializableExtra("note"));
            } else if (resultCode == 2) {
                notes.set(pos, (Note) data.getSerializableExtra("note"));
            }
            listVisibility();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(final int pos) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(recyclerView.getContext())
                .setTitle("Select:")
                .setItems(new String[]{"Read", "Update", "Delete"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        switch (i) {
                            case 0:
                                RoomMarkdownActivity.this.pos = pos;
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        new Intent(getActivity(),
                                                RoomMarkdownViewNoteActivity.class).putExtra(
                                                "note", notes.get(pos)), 100);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                RoomMarkdownActivity.this.pos = pos;
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        new Intent(getActivity(),
                                                RoomMarkdownAddNoteActivity.class).putExtra(
                                                "note", notes.get(pos)), 100);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                noteDatabase.getNoteDao().deleteNote(notes.get(pos));
                                notes.remove(pos);
                                listVisibility();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private void listVisibility() {
        int emptyMsgVisibility = View.GONE;
        if (notes.size() == 0) {
            if (textViewMsg.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                emptyMsgVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
        }
        textViewMsg.setVisibility(emptyMsgVisibility);
        notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        noteDatabase.cleanUp();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

And here is the adapter:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.BeanHolder> {

    private List<Note> list;
    public Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private OnNoteItemClick onNoteItemClick;

    public NotesAdapter(List<Note> list, Context context) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.onNoteItemClick = (OnNoteItemClick) context;
    }

    @Override
    public BeanHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.room_markdown_note_list_item, parent, false);
        return new BeanHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BeanHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.e("bind", "onBindViewHolder: " + list.get(position));
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class BeanHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textViewTitle;

        private BeanHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onNoteItemClick.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface OnNoteItemClick {
        void onNoteClick(int pos);
    }

}
```

It seems there's something broken between `notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, getActivity());` and `this.onNoteItemClick = (OnNoteItemClick) context;`, but I couldn't find a good alternative to `getActivity()` and I guess I solved this one earlier in another approach, however, it was still throwing another similar error if I recall correctly (this file is full of `this` and I don't doubt some `getActivity()` are misplaced).

The code as is compiles, but, as soon as the button that'd call the specific `Fragment` to the screen is clicked, the error is thrown and the app stops running immediately.

I thank you in advance for the attention and help and, please, let me know if you need to know more about this issue so as I'm able to bring more information here.

Comment: You're passing `getActivity()` for the `Context` parameter in your `NotesAdapter` constructor call. That's the `Activity` hosting the `Fragment`, not the `Fragment` itself. Your `Activity` apparently does not implement the `OnNoteItemClick` interface, which is why you get that `Exception`. You want to pass the `Fragment` – i.e., `this` – as the `OnNoteItemClick` implementer. You could change the `Context` parameter to `Fragment`, cast that as your interface, and do the `getActivity()` call in the constructor to get your `Context`.

Comment: Mike, thank you very much for this comment and for your participation in this thread! Your words were enough to show me the way and a simple helper class with most of the code which was inside MainActivity solved this issue (now I just need to understand what to do so that the database content is shown in the right place). And, please, feel free to post your comment as an answer if you like.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-)  It was just a quick suggestion. Thank you, though. I really appreciate the offer. Please do post an answer with your solution, if you would like. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: I'll definitely do it, I just need to make it work as intented first. I wish you a nice weekend around there and thanks again, Mike!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to what [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53452881/java-lang-classcastexception-activity-cannot-be-cast-to-adapter-while-trying-to#comment93778395_53452881) and [Reza.Abedini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53452974/6398434) said among answers and comments I was able to understand what was happening and to overcome this issue.

The problem was in the `Adapter` that was prepared to get `Context` from `Activity` so I had to convert the parameter to `Fragment` and it ended up working like this:

```
public NotesAdapter(List<Note> list, RoomMarkdownActivity fragment) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(fragment.getActivity());
    this.list = list;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.onNoteItemClick = fragment;
}
```

And the `Fragment` like:

```
public class RoomMarkdownActivity extends Fragment implements NotesAdapter.OnNoteItemClick {

    public static RoomMarkdownActivity newInstance() {
        return new RoomMarkdownActivity();
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView textViewMsg;
    NoteDatabase noteDatabase;
    List<Note> notes;
    NotesAdapter notesAdapter;
    int pos;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.room_markdown_activity, container, false);
        textViewMsg = view.findViewById(R.id.textview_empty);
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(listener);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        initializeViews();
        displayList();
        return view;
    }

    private void displayList() {
        noteDatabase = NoteDatabase.getInstance(getActivity());
        new RetrieveTask(this).execute();
    }

    private static class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Note>> {

        private WeakReference<RoomMarkdownActivity> activityReference;

        RetrieveTask(RoomMarkdownActivity context) {
            activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Note> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            if (activityReference.get() != null)
                return activityReference.get().noteDatabase.getNoteDao().getNotes();
            else
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Note> notes) {
            if (notes != null && notes.size() > 0) {
                activityReference.get().notes.clear();
                activityReference.get().notes.addAll(notes);
                activityReference.get().textViewMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                activityReference.get().notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void initializeViews() {
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        notes = new ArrayList<>();
        notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), RoomMarkdownAddNoteActivity.class), 100);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode > 0) {
            if (resultCode == 1) {
                notes.add((Note) data.getSerializableExtra("note"));
            } else if (resultCode == 2) {
                notes.set(pos, (Note) data.getSerializableExtra("note"));
            }
            listVisibility();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNoteClick(final int pos) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Select:")
                .setItems(new String[]{"Read", "Update", "Delete"}, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        switch (i) {
                            case 0:
                                RoomMarkdownActivity.this.pos = pos;
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        new Intent(getActivity(),
                                                RoomMarkdownViewNoteActivity.class).putExtra(
                                                "note", notes.get(pos)), 100);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                RoomMarkdownActivity.this.pos = pos;
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        new Intent(getActivity(),
                                                RoomMarkdownAddNoteActivity.class).putExtra(
                                                "note", notes.get(pos)), 100);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                noteDatabase.getNoteDao().deleteNote(notes.get(pos));
                                notes.remove(pos);
                                listVisibility();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }).show();
    }

    public void listVisibility() {
        int emptyMsgVisibility = View.GONE;
        if (notes.size() == 0) {
            if (textViewMsg.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                emptyMsgVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
        }
        textViewMsg.setVisibility(emptyMsgVisibility);
        notesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        noteDatabase.cleanUp();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Thank you very much for the help and I hope this question/answer helps others as well!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast Activity to OnNoteItemClick because you implement it in your fragment, you can assign a OnNoteItemClick to your adapter so you can change your code to :
adapter:

```
public NotesAdapter(List<Note> list, OnNoteItemClick onNoteItemClick) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
    this.onNoteItemClick = onNoteItemClick;
}
```

initialize your adapter in fragment this way:

```
notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, this); //Your class implements OnNoteItemClick interface so you can use 'this'
```

Comment: Notice `LayoutInflater.from(context)`, `this.context = context;`.

Comment: you are right , we can directly use parent.getContext() in onCreateViewHolder method or pass note fragment and cast it as onNoteItemClick.

Comment: @Reza.Abedini, I'm not sure if I did it the right way, but I tried the approach you suggested - even the "`parent.getContext()` in `onCreateViewHolder`" and what I got was an "attempt to invoke virtual method [...] on a null object reference". I could advance a little bit by creating a helper class, but even though it worked, the item list didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, getActivity());
```

with

```
notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notes, RoomMarkdownActivity.this);
```

Comment: Actually that's how it used to work initially as an `Activity`, but as soon as it started extending `Fragment` this approach isn't accepted anymore ("NotesAdapter (List<Note>, android.content.Context) in NotesAdapter cannot be applied
to (List<Note>, com.example.com.RoomMarkdownActivity)").